# SQL Query to find WHERE 2 datetime columns have matching values AND the values are BETWEEN certain dates

Tags: sql

I apologies in advanced if this seems like a stupid question but it has been plaguing me for days now!

Im trying to run a query to bring back the number of enquiries by "created by" on a very awkward database ive inherited.

Heres what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.UserCode AS 'Created By', 
       u.FullName AS 'User Name', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(p.PersonCode)) AS 'Qty Created'
FROM   dbo.Persons AS p 
JOIN   dbo.AuditLog AS a 
  ON p.PersonCode = a.PersonCode 
JOIN   dbo.Users AS u 
  ON a.UserCode = u.UserCode
WHERE  a.time = p.DateCreated 
       AND (p.DateCreated AND a.time) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18' 
GROUP BY u.UserCode, u.FullName
```

This only brings back:

Created By
10000001

User Name Administrator

Qty Created 1

This I know is wrong because when I take out the 2nd part of the WHERE clause it returns a count from the entire table, im sure its something im doing/not doing but could anyone point me in the right direction or offer some code to as my subject describes?

Thanks

J

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you please show some sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look right:

```
AND (p.DateCreated AND a.time) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18'
```

since you have:

```
 a.time = p.DateCreated
```

the following will do:

```
AND p.DateCreated BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `BETWEEN` attempt is faulty, and redundant as the dates have to be equivalent anyway:

Change:

```
WHERE  a.time = p.DateCreated 
       AND (p.DateCreated AND a.time) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18'
```

To:

```
WHERE  a.time = p.DateCreated 
       AND p.DateCreated BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18'
```

Note, if these are `DATETIME` fields then `BETWEEN` may return undesired results as you are using it, because the default time when none is specified is `00:00:00`.  So any time after midnight on your end date will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing sample data and your desired output, but the first thing that jumps out at me is this line:

```
AND (p.DateCreated AND a.time) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18'
```

Are you trying to say:

```
AND p.DateCreated BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18' 
AND a.time BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-05-18'
```